# Raspberry Pi often "freezes" on a screen when rebooting

Tags: boot

I have a Raspberry Pi 2 B with a fresh install of the latest Raspbian.

I had this trouble before, started researching it, rebooted a couple of times and then the problem seemed to resolve itself. It happened again though and I will need this device to be able to restart and auto login headlessly in the future, so I need to fix this.

Everything seems successful and at the end of the long list of code messages that run on start-up it says

```
Show Plymouth Boot Screen...
```

and the next screen (of death) shows an image saying

> Welcome to the Raspberry Pi Desktop (logo image) Powered by Raspberry
>   Pi"

under that image it says

```
systemd.hostname.service
```

then has a flashing cursor. No keyboard or mouse input is accepted.

Answer (score 0):

I'd get a fresh compatible sd and try with that.

If it weren't a 'fresh' install, I'd say:

Check to see if the keyboard Caps Lock light can toggle. If thats unresponsive then most likely a frozen pi.
Probably not if the cursor is still blinking.

Have you made recent changes to an rc file in the rc startup tree?

Comment: Hi, yes it can toggle NUM LOCK and CAPS LOCK on and off. The SD card was a new Sans Disk I bought earlier that day from Micro Center. The only change I made was to enable auto-login

Comment: The Pi hardware is still running by response from the Caps lock toggle working, but seems to be waiting on a response from the systemd.hostname.service perhaps. Are you hard wired through ethernet? Enabled SSH option in raspi-config? Can you see its ip via ethernet?
I'd re-image a fresh install of Raspbian onto the SD, remove all hardware from the pi, except keyboard, and monitor, and see if you get a boot to a default prompt / setup on the freshly imaged card.. If you get same results as well with this fresh install, SD prob FAIL

run badblocks -v -n /dev/xxxxx  etc to check the SD card

Comment: Yes, I see your logic. It's not hardwired - configured to logon to the ethernet and yes I enabled SSH and auto-login via `raspi-config` so that I can hopefully get it to where it can turn on and off without my needing a monitor. I can try the drastic steps, but man it's going to cost me some time because I just finished putting together a hat and a cardboard enclosure with a speaker. It seems to work fine *sometimes* just not everytime...

Comment: I know what you mean, its sometimes hard to physically get to an SD in an embedded project. 

Can I seek clarification when you mention 'get it to turn on and off' ... What is your method of 'turning on and off' ?

I want to deduct reason why your card is doing that with a fresh install,  I have to say that I've got a small handful of funky SD's that tend to give me problems when trying to install Raspbian. I'd have to buy new SD's at this point to get anywhere. Even new-ish SD's can go funky early when hosting a full blown +rw OS.

I know its a drag,, you might need to open and check SD

Comment: I picked up 2 new micro SD's today so I'll give it a try tonight. By get it to turn on and off, I meant for instance that I'd like to unplug it at home, take it to my office and plug it in there to show people etc, without needing to connect to a monitor.

Comment: Do you simply unplug when you are done? Any shut down? Curious to know how the new SD's do.